# Привязка соц сети к аккаунту php

Tags: php, api, соцсети

Как реализовать привязку соц сети, например ютуб к аккаунту пользователя php
делать отдельную таблицу, где хранить данные из соц сети и id пользователя сайта?

подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм работы

Comment: Если у вас несколько соц. сетей привязать надо, то тут потенциальная связь один-ко-многим и нужна отдельная таблица. Если связь один-к-одному, то вы либо можете расширить текущую таблицу пользователей нужным полем, либо тоже завести отдельную таблицу с точки зрения логического разбиения данных в разные сущности. зависит от сценария использования.

Comment: что значит "аккаунту пользователя php"?